# when app is in background notification action buttons not showing android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

When the application is in background I am not able to get the action buttons.
It works only when the app is in the foreground.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // create channel in new versions of android
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("Test", "Test Notification", importance);
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            // show notification


            Intent positive = new Intent(this, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
            positive.putExtra("notiID", "1");
            positive.setAction("Info");


            Intent redoplacement = new Intent(this, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
            redoplacement.putExtra("notiID", "2");
            redoplacement.setAction("Call");


            PendingIntent pIntent_positive = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, positive, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            PendingIntent redoplacementintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, redoplacement, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            // 0 is request code
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Test")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent1)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setWhen(0)
                            .addAction(0, "Info", pIntent_positive)
                            .addAction(0, "Call", redoplacementintent);

            // 0 is id of notification
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: Anything to be added in the manifest?Or should i add in the payloads?

Comment: When you use Data Messages and your app is in the background or closed notifications are handled by the system tray. I think this should do the trick: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification

Comment: And when this must be called?

Comment: Try to modify your notificationManager.

Comment: same issue i am facing..